# How to get the selected value from dropdown list through javascript and set the value selected in java bean?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How can I get the current value of a selected dropdown list value using Javascript?
I have a user contact form in which I have a dropdown list and the value selected in the list must be captured by javascript function and then pass this value to the controller and set the bean value and then persist the value in database.

The list is like,

```
<select id="ddl">
    <option value="val1">Optoion 1</option>
    <option value="val2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

To return the string from the list

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].val();
```

Which would make `selected` be `val2`

How do I access this value in Java class and store the value in database?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different, almost totally unrelated languages.

Comment: @Pointy: "almost"? :) That piece of propaganda (naming JS) has screwed so many people over the years.

Comment: i know but do you know how to do that in java...i have no idea about that

Comment: @Lakshmanan doing it from Java makes little sense. Do you mean a Java applet? Do you have server-side code written in Java?

Comment: i have a bean class in java... and i need to store all the form values into that...

Comment: Your Java code is running on the server, where it can not access the HTML elements like JavaScript can. You would have to send the data up to the server with a form post or AJAX call.

Comment: Ya am using an ajax call...i serialize the form data and send it ajax call..but the data is not moving to the controller class..all the fields are null over there...i tried to alert(data); and it alerts the data been serialized...how do i transfer my control to a controller(ContactController) now with the serialized data or maybe possibly bind the values to the setters in the bean class(ContactForm)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled the request with ajax call and transferred control to a Spring Controller..I wrote this code in my controller..

```
@Controller
public class ContactController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/contact/processContact", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> processWriteToUs(@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model){
Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try { 
         Contact contact = new Contact();
         contact.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
         contact.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstname"));
         contact.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastname"));
         contact.setType(request.getParameter("ddl"));
                     //process the form details...
                     //responseMap.put("key","value")
        }
        catch{Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return responseMap;
          }
    }
```

and now finally that works as expected...

Answer (score 3):

Submit your form to a servlet

to fetch the selected value, use this code in your servlet

> ```
> String str=(String)req.getParameter("selectboxname");
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get value of select value of drop down then use this

```
document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
```

If you want to get text of select index then

```
document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").options[document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Its not the right answer to this question, but its the right answer to the question which brought me here. Thanks!